# Iterate element attributes using angular.element

Tags: angularjs

How can I iterate element attributes using angular.element?

Can I use jquery in my custom directives? If yes, Do I need to recompile my controller after DOM manipulation

Comment: Can you? Yes. Should you? Not unless you really have to. Do you need to recompile after? Only if adding new markup that contains directives.

Comment: what if I am adding new directives to existing markup?

Comment: Yes, you will need to compile. Though I think this can be dangerous, because it will recompile any existing directives on that same element, which may be problematic or at the very least inefficient.